# a SAML toolkit for PHP from OneLogin.com

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml, federated-identity

I want to set up a identity-provider in my application.
I saw a SAML toolkit for PHP from OneLogin.com (http://support.onelogin.com/entries/268420-saml-toolkit-for-php). How can I use it for setting up a identity provider in my machine?

I felt that we can use it for setting up a service-provider not identity-provider. Let me know your views.

Answer (score 1):

This toolkit is for use with OneLogin as an identity provider. 
If you want to set up an identity provider locally that is not OneLogin, you should find some other software that will do this.

Answer (score 0):

If it can help you... There's a GPL licensed library implementing SAML IDP in PHP https://github.com/lightSAML/lightSAML-IDP but it's in early beta.